# Change JSON attribute name on POST in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

So a Rails-API is supposed to accept a JSON post for

```
{
"post": {  "users": [{"name": "James"}]}
}
```

now the problem is, I am using nested_attributes, in the Post model I have the line:

```
     `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`
```

How can I accept in a POST the attribute name "users" instead of "users_attributes"?

posts_controller.rb

```
def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)
users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes)
params.values[0][:users] = users


if @post.save
  render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post
else
  render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
end
```

...

```
   def post_params
      users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes) params.values[0][:users] = users
      params.require(:post).permit(:expiration, :users => [:name, :dates], :users_attributes => [:name, :post_id, :dates => []])

   end
 end
```

Comment: have you tried adding it to model as `attr_accesible :name, :users_attributes`

Comment: @Sontya, I have already done that, but that isnt the issue, I want to accept JSON requests calling it "users", not "users_attributes"

Comment: try this `params = { post: { user_attributes: { id: '20', name: 'war' } } }
post.update params[:post]` or `post = Post.create(params[:post])` and then you can call `post.users`

Comment: @Sontya I want to post with JSON like this { "post": { "users": [{...}]}} but all that works currently is, { "post": { "users_attributes": [{...}]}} how can I change this name in the Rails controller?

Comment: at the end in controller there will be a `private` method `def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name)
    end` something like this where is that

Comment: @Sontya I added that part.

Comment: But it's `package_params` method and you are calling `Post.new(post_params)`. You can add `users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes)
params.values[0][:users] = users` this code to this method at start

Comment: @Sontya sorry I updated it, its supposed to be post_params

Comment: `def post_params users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes) params.values[0][:users] = users end`

Comment: Is it working now, add those two lines in `post_params` method. And remove from `create` method

Comment: @Sontya, like this? I tried this , its not working ; (

Comment: I will update my answer, according to your `controller` code

Comment: dude I told you, put those two lines at the start of the `post_params` method,

Comment: @Sontya Yes! that worked, BUT, the value in the hash is not getting stored.   i.e. suppose the post is {"post": {"users": [ {"name" => 'James'}]}}, when it saves, users is blank.

Comment: @Sontya I switched users_attributes with users and it saves! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

Suppose your params are

```
params = { post: {
name: 'war', users_attributes: [
{ title: 'Ruby documentation browser!' },
{ title: 'the modern citizen' },
{ title: '', destroy: '1' }]}}

users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes)
params.values[0][:users] = users
```

Comment: that didnt work. Just wanted to be clear "users_attributes" will work when posting, but I only want to use the name "users"

Comment: This should work, it's working for me. See I updated it

Comment: The problem is when someone is posting with JSON and does { post: { name: 'war', users: [{...}]}  , users_attributes will work

Comment: params value will be `{:post=>{:name=>"war", :users=>[{:title=>"Ruby documentation browser!"}, {:title=>"the modern citizen"}, {:title=>"", :destroy=>"1"}]}}`

Comment: yes, ok, so im putting that code in my Create method, but its throwing an error.      def create
    "@post = Post.new(package_params)
    users = params.values[0].delete(:users_attributes)
    params.values[0][:users] = users"

Comment: yes, dude it will throw the error. see yours is `package_params` and I specified as `params` modify accordingly or post your controller code.

Comment: i am posting the controller

Comment: switch users and users_attributes, but THIS WORKED